# Python 3 "type" keyword throwing syntax error

Tags: python-3.x

When I define Position as mentioned below:

```
type Position = int * int
```

I get a run time error as shown below:

```
type Position = int * int
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can you please suggest how to fix this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to declare Position as?

Comment: In python you generally dont need to declare types, type is a function that would be used like type(Position) to return the type of the variable, not declare it

Answer (score 1):

In python you generally don't need to declare types

`type` is a function : [`type()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-type-function/)

You can use it to return the type of the variable, but you don't have to(can't) declare a type for a variable.

So you can just do this:

```
Position = 1234 * 5678 # whatever integer you want
```